# Direcionar click do botão para dentro do item_databound da tabela

Tags: c#

Tenho uma tabela dentro de um repeater. Nessa table existe um botão. O que eu quero é quando eu clicar nesse botão, ele dispara o evento do repeater: `rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemDataBound`, apenas isso. Como eu faço isso? O meu botão é esse:

```
<td>
  <asp:Button ID="btnConsultarProcessos" OnClick="btnConsultarProcessos_Click"  runat="server" Text="Consultar processo" CssClass="acessos" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pelo que eu entendi você precisa de algo tipo isso, não ?

```
protected void rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Procurando o botão no Repeater
    var button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnConsultarProcessos");

    // Verificando senão está nulo.
    if (button == null) return;

    // Associando evento ao botão.
    button.Click += btnConsultarProcessos_Click;

    button.CommandName = "Excluir";
    button.CommandArgument = "1234";
}

protected void btnConsultarProcessos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Faça algo ...
}
```

ou então, você pode utilizar o ItemCommand do Repeater.

```
protected void rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Procurando o botão no Repeater
    var button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnConsultarProcessos");

    // Verificando senão está nulo.
    if (button == null) return;

    if (button.CommandName == "Excluir")
    {
        this.ExcluirRegistro(button.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```