# Dificuldade para tratar evento de botão no itemcommand do repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma table em um repeater. Nessa table tenho um Button e um LinkButton. Acontece que preciso pegar qual evento click foi disparado se do button ou do linkbutton. Tentei fazer um if, mas deu erro de serem incompatíveis o button e o linkbutton. Se eu fizer isso, sempre terei a propriedade Text do button e nunca o if vai funcionar: 
`var btnConsultar = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnConsultarProcessos");`

Esse é meu ItemCommand

```
protected void rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //Declarações
            HiddenField vhdfCdProcesso = null;
            HiddenField vhdfCdAnalise = null;
            HiddenField vhdfCdUsuario = null;

            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializalções
                vhdfCdProcesso = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdfCdProcesso");
                vhdfCdAnalise = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdfCdAnalise");
                vhdfCdUsuario = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdfCdUsuario");

                var btnConsultar = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnConsultarProcessos");

                //Desenvolvimento 


                if (vhdfCdProcesso != null)
                    hdfCdProcessoPriozar.Value = vhdfCdProcesso.Value;
                else
                    hdfCdProcessoPriozar.Value = string.Empty;

                if (vhdfCdAnalise != null)
                    if (vhdfCdAnalise.Value != string.Empty)
                        hdfCdAnalisePriorizar.Value = vhdfCdAnalise.Value;
                    else
                        hdfCdAnalisePriorizar.Value = string.Empty;
                else
                    hdfCdAnalisePriorizar.Value = string.Empty;

                if (vhdfCdUsuario != null)
                    if (vhdfCdUsuario.Value != string.Empty)
                        listaUsuariosDropDownList.SelectedValue = vhdfCdUsuario.Value;

                pnlPriorizar.Visible = true;




            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
                Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

No meu evento OnClick do botão eu não tenho nada. O que eu quero é que quando eu clicar no botão ele faz algo e quando eu clicar no linkbutton faz outra coisa. O linkbutton está funcionando. O button é que é uma nova tarefa para eu fazer e como eu pego um click pou algo assim para dizer que o botão clicado é um e não o outro. A parte do btnConsultar é o que eu estou tentando fazer.

Answer (score 1):

como exemplifiquei no outro [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40827/direcionar-click-do-bot%C3%A3o-para-dentro-do-item-databound-da-tabela/40833#40833), basta você associar o método do evento ao click do botão e do link.

Veja se o exemplo abaixo lhe atende:

```
protected void rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Procurando controles no Repeater
    var button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnConsultarProcessos");
    var link = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkConsultarProcessos");

    // Associando eventos.
    button.Click += btnConsultarProcessos_Click;
    link.Click += lnkEnviar_Click;
}
```

Metódos:

```
// Button
protected void btnConsultarProcessos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Faça algo ...
}

// Linkbutton
protected void lnkEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Faça algo ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz assim:

```
Type vintTipo = e.CommandSource.GetType();
if (vintTipo == typeof(Button))
{
   //Aqui faço coisas
}
else
{
   //Aqui faço outras coisas
}
```